# write a formula to find the inverse of a matrix

Tags: r, matrix

I need to find write a formula to breakdown a matrix using the blockwise inversion method.This what I have so far

```
func <- function(matrix=M) {
  n = nrow(M)
  if (n==1) M^-1

  } else if (n==2) {
    1/DetM*(M)

    CMHope=matrix(c(M[2,2],-1*M[2,1]))
    CMHope2=matrix(c(-1*M[1,2],M[1,1]))
    Rbbin=cbind(CMHope,CMHope2)
    1/det(M)*Rbbin
  } else {

 }
  return(end matrix)
}
```

Comment: Fix your code. Some braces are missing. See there is no brace after `if` and next brace pairs with function's opening brace.

Comment: Probably you already know but if you just need to inverse a matrix you could use `solve(M)`